# timezone inconsistency when parsing datetime Strings

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I convert two types of Strings to an ISO format using `SimpleDateFormat` for parsing and `org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateFormatUtils` for formatting (since they provide a ISO formatter out-of-the-box).
The pattern Strings for parsing are `M/d/y H:m` and `d.M.y H:m`. A typical String to convert may look either like `4/14/2009 11:22` or `4.14.2009 11:22`. I initialize the parsers as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat SLASH = new SimpleDateFormat(PATTERN_S, Locale.getDefault());
SimpleDateFormat DOT = new SimpleDateFormat(PATTERN_D, Locale.getDefault());
```

I get the the formatter:

```
  FastDateFormat isoFormatter = DateFormatUtils.ISO_DATETIME_TIME_ZONE_FORMAT
```

After creating a `Date` from the parsed String:

```
Date date = FORMAT_SLASH.parse(old);
```

it is formatted for output:

```
isoFormatter.format(date)
```

The strange thing is : when a `String` with slashes was converted, the output looks like `2009-04-14T11:42:00+01:00` (which is correct) but when a `String` with dots was converted, the output looks like `2010-02-14T11:42:00+02:00`, shifting my timezone to somewhere between Finland and South Africa, the year to 2010 and the month to february

What is going wrong here and why?

**EDIT** : changed the output strings to match real output (damn you, cut-n-paste). The reason was the interchanged `M` and `d` in the pattern strings that I failed to notice. `14` seems to be a perfecty valid month - its next year's february and even non-lenient settings can't force the formatter to reject it. The timeshift issue is resolved and the reason for the TimeZone change is provided by Jim Garrison. Thanks Ahmad and Jim

Comment: Is your dot-string really `4.14.2009 11:22`? This does not fit to the format string.

Comment: Please re-read your post and fix errors, if any, having to do with m/d/y vs d.m.y and be sure you are showing us the correct input and output.  I suspect you have issues with one date being interpreted with month and day backwards.  If the resulting date (2010/02/04?) is on the other side of a DST boundary you could indeed get a 1 hour offset.

Comment: @Paulo Ebermann - it really is - and it converts. I thought it to be the lenient settings but the pattern seems to match even with strict setting

Comment: @Jim Garrison - i guess you're right about the shift. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dot pattern is `d.M.y H:m` while your example shows that you meant `M.d.y H:m`, I supposed this would throw a `ParseException`, but it doesn't and it causes timezone issues.

Comment: The exception throwing can be adjusted with DateFormat.setLenient(false). But giving interchanged month and day values would not really produce the output given here.